# Mysql bulk insert not inserting all data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, insert

I have to insert many data from excel to a table (about 4000 rows ) throught Ajax inside a loop i use :

```
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO ".$params["table"]." (".$colonnes_string.") VALUES (".$row.")";
```

This query works fine but it insert only 1000 rows of 4000, may be some insert have error why i set IGNORE statement, but it still not insert above 1000 rows.

How can i skip insert error and continue the query ?

Thank you.

Comment: How big are the rows you're trying to insert?

Comment: if you use Insert ignore the row actually won't insert if it results on duplicate key ... no wonder why only 1000 rows get inserted

Comment: May be this post is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: I try to insert 4800 rows

Answer (score 1):

Please use **INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** syntax instead of **IGNORE**
Here's a link to a similar question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238472/how-to-insert-update-a-large-amount-of-data-into-mysql-using-php

Answer (score 0):

You can insert multiple rows with that syntax :

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO some_table 
        (column_name) 
    VALUES 
        ('value'),
        ('another value'),
        ('and again'),
        ...
        ('a last one');
";
```

So, you'll have to build the query with all your `VALUES` and then `INSERT` them all at once.

i.e. :

```
// Set the first part of the query with table name and column(s)
$query = "INSERT INTO some_table (some_column) VALUES ";

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // concatenate the query with values in a loop
    $query .= "(".$row."),";
}

// replace last comma with semi-column to get the right syntax
$query = substring($query, 0, -1).";";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, i don't understand your query, why $rows[$i] than $row[$i] ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Thank you, so row is an array? i have not to implode this ?

Comment: No, `$rows` is the array. `$row` handles the value. You could use this syntax too : `foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {$query += "(".$value."),";}`

Comment: Hello, why i have 0 when echoing query variable ?
$query = "INSERT INTO ".$params["table"]." (".$colonnes_string.") VALUES ";
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
                        $query += "(".$row."),";
}
echo $query;

Comment: Do you use `+=` to add values to the `$query` string ?

Comment: could you explain me please the meaning of $query = substring($query, 0, -1).";";  ?

Comment: As i use wordpress i execute query like this : 
$insert = $wpdb->query($query); but it produce 500 error

Comment: Sorry correct operator is `.=`. The meaning of the substring function is commented.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, i solved it, the error is about characters not escaped, i have to put " around string than ', mysql_real_escape_string  not wroking on my case.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You can post your own answer just for future users.